# How can I add a single image frame to the end of my Youtube video?

Tags: youtube

I have a video game video and I want to attach the summary/scoreboard screenshot to the end of the video. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Make a screencast of the scoreboard that lasts few seconds.
Upload it to youtube.
Use http://www.youtube.com/editor to merge the two videos.